# Database that let me call data from a search box

Tags: android, database

I want to make a app that is a search engine, that when data has been called (e.g. user inputs the car they're looking for) an activity will appear with information i.e text and images. It's only going to be data on cars of my choice, of around 300. Can I have a lot of activity being called from a database without it being slow?

This the best idea I have at the moment for searching for information with text and image that can be called once the users inputs text

Comment: this is pretty vague, theres a ton of possibilities that you can put together with activitys and databases, different structures, subactivitys.....

Comment: sorry just not to sure myself.Wot am really saying is that i know you can call data from the DB but i want to know how to call a activity of information i.e pictures and text.And from what iv been reading is thats is all about table in database with text nothing about calling activity(pages) with info.

Comment: well you can get information from the database doing a query and storing it into variables from the cursor that the query returns, you can do whatever you want with that information

Comment: Good man thats what i wanted to hear